# Entity Framework Newbie - Save to DB

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have 3 joined tables; *ValidationRun* has many *Result* which has many *Error*

The following code succeeds in saving to the Result and Error tables but not the ValidationRun.

Can you see the problem please?

```
 private void WriteResultsToDB(SqlDataReader dr, XMLValidator validator)    
        {    
            using (var context = new ValidationResultsEntities())    
            {    
            var run = new ValidationRun { DateTime = DateTime.Now, XSDPath = this.txtXsd.Text };    

            //loop through table containing the processed XML    
            while (dr.Read())    
            {    
                var result = new Result    
                {    
                    AddedDateTime = (DateTime)dr["Added"],    
                    CustomerAcc = (string)dr["CustomerAcc"],    
                    CustomerRef = (string)dr["CustomerRef"]    
                };    

                if (this.rdoRequest.Checked)    
                {    
                    result.XMLMsg = (string)dr["RequestMSG"];    
                }    
                else    
                {    
                    result.XMLMsg = (string)dr["ReplyMSG"];    
                }    

                if (validator.Validate(result.XMLMsg))    
                {    
                    foreach (string error in validator.Errors)    
                    {    
                        result.Errors.Add(new Error { ErrorDescription = error });    
                    }    
                }    
                else    
                {    
                    //validator caught an error    
                    result.Errors.Add(new Error { ErrorDescription = "XML could not be parsed" });    
                }    

                if (result.Errors.Count == 0) result.ValidFile = true; else result.ValidFile = false;    

                context.AddToResults(result);    
                context.SaveChanges();    
            }    
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to be adding the run to any part of the context. If it were referenced by the result you are adding, perhaps, the change tracker would know it was supposed to be saved, but as it is written it is just some orphaned object that doesn't get attached anywhere.

Comment: Yep, that's it thanks. I got it working by adding "run.Results.Add(result);"